# Character movement stops on every second "Resume" button press

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Im fairly new to Unity and I am trying to make a Pause overlay for my game. Currently Resume does not resume the character movement half of the time. So the first time I pause the game and click resume the overlay is disabled but I will not be able to move, but if I press escape again and then Resume it works fine on the second try. One thing to note is that it works as intended if I press escape while in the pause menu and the logic is exactly the same. Here is my C# script:

```
public class PauseGame : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Canvas;
    bool pausedGame = false;

    // Make sure pause screen is not active on game start
    void Start()
    {
        Canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (pausedGame == false)
            {
                Time.timeScale = 0;
                Canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
                pausedGame = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Time.timeScale = 1;
                Canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
                pausedGame = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resume()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        Canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
        pausedGame = false;
    }

    public void MainMenu()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene("MainMenu");
    }
}
```

Let me know if I should add screenshots of my components.

Comment: So when you press "Resume", the method `Resume` gets called and the canvas is disabled but the time scale is not set to `1`? Is this what's happening?

Comment: I'd use Resume() on a keypress also, you are duplicating code. And Pause() also, for when you will have a menu button in game. You can see all games have such. Less code is better, more readable code also.
Also, also, please cache things like Canvas.GetComponent<Canvas>() in a variable in OnEnabled()

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Your comment made me think, I found out the issue was not timescale since everything was moving except the player. I found out it was the player controller not getting unpaused! Thank you:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution to this! For some reason the FirstPersonAIO controller did not get unpaused when I resumed the game. Where player is a public variable I added these two lines to my code and it fixed my problem:

```
controllerScript = player.GetComponent<FirstPersonAIO>();
controllerScript.ControllerPause();
```